# Insert Ignore query giving error in gorm golang

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a list of genres that I am trying to insert into the database. This is to be done just once when the application runs for the very first time. Hence, I am trying to insert ignore but it is giving me some error.

The GenreCategoires struct:

```
type GenreCategories struct {
    Category string `gorm:"unique"`
}
```

The query is as follows:

```
func (a *App) setupGenreCategories() {
    for _, value := range handler.GenreCategorySlice {
        a.DB.Clauses(clause.Insert{Modifier: "ignore"}).Create(&models.GenreCategories{
            Category: value,
        })
        // Alternate approach but with the same errors:
        if a.DB.Model(&models.GenreCategories{}).Where("category = ?", value).RowsAffected == 0 {
            a.DB.Create(&models.GenreCategories{
                Category: value,
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error that I am receiving:

```
near "ignore": syntax error
[0.019ms] [rows:0] INSERT ignore INTO `genre_categories` (`category`) VALUES ("sunsets")
```

For the alternate approach, the error is as follows:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: genre_categories.category
[0.056ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `genre_categories` (`category`) VALUES ("sunsets")
```

Is my syntax wrong or related to gorm v2, I am using gorm v1.22, hope this information is sufficient. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which database server?

Comment: @DanielFarrell sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using MySQL syntax for Sqlite3, which will obviously cause issues.  In sqlite you need to do `INSERT OR IGNORE`, not `INSERT IGNORE`, so you most likely simply need to change

```
a.DB.Clauses(clause.Insert{Modifier: "ignore"})
```

to

```
a.DB.Clauses(clause.Insert{Modifier: "or ignore"})
```